# MutationRecord seems incomplete at the time it is observed?

Tags: javascript

I'm using a MutationObserver to notice when a certain element is added to the page. The way I do this is by observing the `document` and iterating through each MutationRecord's `addedNodes` array and querying for a certain selector:
`added_node.querySelectorAll("tr[data-testid|='issue-table--row']")`

This does work, but I do not get the results I expect. For example, on a particular page I should see a parentNode being added that has 18 of the `tr` html element somewhere in the tree.

So I created a script to debug this. What you see below, does output how many `tr` elements are found in the added Nodes. As well as each MutationRecord it inspects.

Oddly enough, when searchRecord() is invoked automatically during the scripts runtime, I don't see the expected result.

But after manually reviewing all MutationRecords that were printed to the debug logs, I could confirm that one of them indeed has the data I am looking for.

For example, this manual line in the debug console does return what I expect:
`temp0[1].addedNodes[2].querySelectorAll("tr[data-testid|='issue-table--row']")`
(temp0 being a MutationRecord the MutationObserver observed.)

Typing this into the debug console also yields the expected results:
`searchRecord(temp0)`

But when the same line is invoked by the script via the callback     `searchRecord(mutationRecords)` then for some dubious reason it never returns the expected result.

What's happening? Is the MutationRecord incomplete at the time it is observed??

```js
function searchRecord(mutationRecords) {
    for (const r of mutationRecords) {

        /* TARGET tests */

        if (r.target instanceof HTMLElement) {
            if (r.target.attributes["data-testid"] === "issue-table--body") {
                console.debug("Target is 'issue-table--body'")
            }

            if (r.target.attributes["data-testid"] === "issue-table--row") {
                console.debug("Target is 'issue-table--row'")
            }
        }

        /* ADDEDNODES tests */

        for (const node of r.addedNodes) {
            if (node instanceof HTMLElement) {

                /* direct */

                if (node.attributes["data-testid"] === "issue-table--body") {
                    console.debug("Added node is 'issue-table--body'")
                    console.debug(node)
                }

                if (node.attributes["data-testid"] === "issue-table--row") {
                    console.debug("Added node is 'issue-table--row'")
                    console.debug(node)
                }

                /* nested */

                tbodies = node.querySelectorAll("tbody[data-testid|='issue-table--body']")
                if (tbodies.length > 0) {
                    console.debug(`Added node contains ${tbodies.length} 'issue-table--body'`)
                    console.debug(node)
                }

                trows = node.querySelectorAll("tr[data-testid|='issue-table--row']")
                if (trows.length > 0) {
                    console.debug(`Added node contains ${trows.length} 'issue-table--row'`)
                    console.debug(node)
                }
            }
        }

        /* REMOVEDNODES tests */

        for (const node of r.removedNodes) {
            if (node instanceof HTMLElement) {

                /* direct */

                if (node.attributes["data-testid"] === "issue-table--body") {
                    console.debug("Removed node is 'issue-table--body'")
                }

                if (node.attributes["data-testid"] === "issue-table--row") {
                    console.debug("Removed node is 'issue-table--row'")
                }

                /* nested */

                tbodies = node.querySelectorAll("tbody[data-testid|='issue-table--body']")
                if (tbodies.length > 0) {
                    console.debug(`Removed node contains ${tbodies.length} 'issue-table--body'`)
                }

                trows = node.querySelectorAll("tr[data-testid|='issue-table--row']")
                if (trows.length > 0) {
                    console.debug(`Removed node contains ${trows.length} 'issue-table--row'`)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

new MutationObserver(function callback(mutationRecords) {
    console.debug("-----------------------------------------------")
    console.debug("Mutation observed. Logging mutation records ...")
    console.debug(mutationRecords)

    searchRecord(mutationRecords)

}).observe(document, {
    attributes: false,
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
})
```

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). I think we'll struggle to be able to help if we can't see the issue happening in front of us.

Comment: But I do notice a recurring problem with the code in the question: It seems to be using undeclared identifiers in the loops, such as `for (r of mutationRecords) {` where it's using an undeclared identifier `r` (or at least, if it's declared, it's outside of the function -- and really should be scoped only to the function or, ideally, to the loop). If your loops call anything that *also* assigns to those identifiers, you're going to get very weird cross-talk. (If you aren't declaring them, your code is falling prey to what I call ...

Comment: ... [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) and it would benefit from being moved to [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), where assigning to undeclared identifiers is the error it always should have been). To scope them to the loop, declare them in the `for-of`: `for (const r of mutationRecords)`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't know how I could provide a working example. The system I'm observing is internal. I provided the code to help explain the issue, but the primary question is: *Is the MutationRecord incomplete at the time it is observed?* Because that is now what I see. Thanks for hinting at the code improvement in my for loop. I changed that, but it didn't change that the MutationRecord is incomplete at the time of the callback.

Comment: As it says in the link, you don't provide the whole internal system, you provide a **minimal** example showing the problem you're observing (and the link also explains why this is useful to you, even irrespective of your question). Fundamentally, the nodes you get in the records **are** the nodes, not copies of them, so of course if they're "complete" in the DOM as of when you're observing them, they'll be complete. If they're still being built, they won't be. The exact nature of the problem you're having, and how to solve it, will be down to the details of the code you're using.

Comment: The code above is the one I use. I plop that into the console unmodified and inspect the results in the console. This is alreay a minimal troubleshooting code, of my original code, which is more complex.

Comment: This only shows how you react to changes. It doesn't, critically, show **how the changes are being made**. Please do read through the links above: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)

Comment: I don't know how the changes are being made. I'm trying to create a userscript for Jira and I have no knowledge how that web app works. Thanks for your answer, I'll look at it immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's simplify the situation to make it easier to talk about: You want to watch for `div` elements with class `example` (`div.example`) being added and see how many `span` elements with class `x` (`span.x`) there are in the `div.example` that was added.

The nodes you receive are the actual nodes in the DOM document that were added. They will be as fully-populated as they are as of when your observer was called, which will be at some point after the element has been added to the container (because of JavaScript's run-to-completion semantics — the code adding the elements has to finish before any callbacks that triggers, such as your mutation observer, can be run). That means that:

1. If a `div.example` is added that contains (say) three `span.x` elements, your code will see the three `span.x` elements in the `div` when your observer callback is called, since they're already there.
2. If a `div.example` is added, then just afterward three `span.x` elements are added to it without yielding to the event loop (that is, without waiting for some asynchronous operation like ajax or a `setTimeout`), your code will still see those three `span.x` elements in the `div.example` when the observer callback is called, because they're there by the time it runs, even though they weren't when the `div.example` was first added.

   - Variation: If the `div.example` is added with `span` elements in it that don't have the `x` class yet, but then the `x` class is added afterward without yielding to the event loop, your code will see `span.x` elements, because the class will be there by the time it runs.
3. If a `div.example` is added, and then the `span.x` elements are added to it later **after** the code adding things has yielded to the event loop by waiting for some asynchronous operation, your code **may not** see the `span.x` elements in the `div.example`, since it may run before they're there.

   - Variation: If the `div.example` is added with `span` elements in it that don't have the `x` class yet, but then later **after** the code adding things has yielded to the event loop it adds the `x` class to the `span` elements, your code **may not** see `span.x` elements in the `div.example`, because although the `span` elements are there, they don't have the `x` class you're looking for yet, because your code ran before the class was added.

Here's an example of all three scenarios:

```js
const observer = new MutationObserver((records) => {
  for (const record of records) {
if (record.addedNodes) {
  for (const node of record.addedNodes) {
    if (node.nodeName === "DIV" && node.classList.contains("example")) {
      const {
        length
      } = node.querySelectorAll("span.x");
      console.log(`div.example "${node.id}" added, ${length} span.x elements found in it`);
    }

    if (node.querySelectorAll("span").length > 0) {
      node.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen"
    }
  }
}
  }
});

const container = document.getElementById("container");
observer.observe(container, {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
});

function createDiv(id) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.id = id;
  div.classList.add("example");
  return div;
}

function addSpan(div, text) {
  div.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<span class=x>${text}</span>`);
}

setTimeout(() => {
  let div;

  // Adding a fully-set-up div
  div = createDiv("A: three spans");
  addSpan(div, "1");
  addSpan(div, "2");
  addSpan(div, "3");
  console.log("A: spans added");
  container.appendChild(div);

  // Adding a partially-set-up div, then adding to it after, but without
  // yielding to the event loop
  div = createDiv("B: three spans, added after (no yield)");
  container.appendChild(div);
  addSpan(div, "1");
  addSpan(div, "2");
  addSpan(div, "3");
  console.log("B: spans added");

  // Adding a partially-set-up div, then adding to it after yielding to
  // the event loop
  div = createDiv("C: three spans, added after (yield)");
  container.appendChild(div);
  setTimeout(() => {
addSpan(div, "1");
addSpan(div, "2");
addSpan(div, "3");
console.log("C: spans added");
  }, 0);
}, 100);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 70% !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

So if you're seeing the element without the descendants you expect to see, it would appear you're running into scenario #3 above: The descendants are being added to it (or the charateristics of them you're looking for are set) after a delay.

The crucial point is: The elements you get in the observer callback are the actual elements in the DOM, so they'll have the contents and characteristics those elements have as of when you look at them. They aren't copies or placeholders or representative examples.

Comment: Thanks for that, actually. So I did some experiments with that. I understand your points that querying for a nested set, it may not yield a result when the addedNode is not yet fully populated. But the querySelector in my code does not query for nested objects. So even if the child node is added later, it should still be observed by the MutationObserver, now? So I added a simple `querySelectorAll("span")` to see whether the MutationObserver will observe all spans being added. And it turns out, in the third example none of the spans are observed at any time. Can you explain why?

Comment: @Daniel - *"But the querySelector in my code does not query for nested objects."* That's the only thing `querySelector(All)` can do, look for child and descendant elements. `addedNode.querySelector("span")` won't return `addedNode`, whether it's a `span` or not. It would only include `span` elements that are **inside** that `span`. If you want to know if `addedNode`, itself, matches a selector, use [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) on it.

Comment: That was it. The combination of the delayed addition of the node (option 3) together with the catch that the querySelector does select only on child nodes. Thanks a lot!